# Is it possible to display an External Web Page Content in a Modal? (AngularJS+Bootstrap+Html+CSS)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is it possible to display an External Web Page Content in a Modal? Both of them are my sites. (AngularJS+Bootstrap+Html+CSS)

Comment: yes, with iframes

Comment: ```
$('.modal').on('shown.bs.modal',function(){      //correct here use 'shown.bs.modal' event which comes in bootstrap3
  $(this).find('iframe').attr('src','http://www.google.com')
})
```

Comment: @saifali thank you for your support but i'm not using jquerry.